# To calculate $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \Big(\sum_{m=1}^r (a_m)^n\Big)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_1 , a_2 , ..., a_r$ be positive real numbers such that $a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_r$. Without any more information given , can we exactly calculate $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigg(\sum_{m=1}^r (a_m)^n\Bigg)^{1/n}\ ?$$

Comment: You can probably upper-bound it using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality; have you tried it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, since $a_1 > a_2 > \cdots >a_r$, we have
$$a_1^n < \sum_{m=1}^r a_m^n <r a_1^n$$
Hence,
$$a_1 < \left( \sum_{m=1}^r a_m^n \right)^{1/n} < r^{1/n} a_1$$
Now you should be able to finish it off. (**HINT**: What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} r^{1/n}$?)